# iterating over multiple dictionaries inside a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is my list with multiple dictionaries inside:

```
tags: [{
        'key': 'Environment',
        'value': 'Production'
    }, {
        'key': 'Environment',
        'value': 'Acceptance'
    }, {
        'key': 'Environment',
        'value': 'Test'
    }, {
        'key': 'Environment',
        'value': 'Development'
    }, {
        'key': 'Environment',
        'value': 'Sandbox'
    }]
```

Here the key value is always 'Environment' for all dictionaries. I need to check if the key is Environment, check if values are Production,Test,Development and Sandbox. If yes, print something.

How can achieve this ?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. It's customary on SO, as someone with a couple of hundred reps should know.

Comment: The marked duplicate has many examples. If you need something more specific and are stuck, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53517423/edit) with code from your latest attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
tags = [{
        'key': 'Environment',
        'value': 'Production'
    }, {
        'key': 'Environment',
        'value': 'Acceptance'
    }, {
        'key': 'Environment',
        'value': 'Test'
    }, {
        'key': 'Environment',
        'value': 'Development'
    }, {
        'key': 'Environment',
        'value': 'Sandbox'
    }]

result = all(tag['value'] in ('Sandbox', 'Test', 'Development', 'Production') for tag in tags if tag['key'] == 'Environment')
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
False
```

Note that the output is False because it contains the value `'Acceptance'`.

Comment: this worked. thanks @Daniel Mesejo